# How to use a DAO module in a main class Java?

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection

I need to use a class object into a main class, but I'm get some problems:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoElementFoundException {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fantacalcio_rest");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

}
```

And this is my

> persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="fantacalcio_rest">
        <jta-data-source>java:/fantacalcio_rest</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Player</class>
        <class>model.Module</class>
        <class>model.User</class>
        <class>model.League</class>
        <class>model.FantaPlayer</class>

        <class>model.PlayerTransfer</class>
        <class>model.Formation</class>
        <class>model.PlayerMark</class>
        <class>model.FantaPlayerMatch</class>
        <class>model.CalendarSerieA</class>
        <class>model.FantaPlayerRank</class>
        <class>model.RankRow</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Where am I wrong? How Can I use the DAO without any problem in a Java Class?

Comment: I know how they works, the problem I'm getting trouble how to use in a Java SE; could you please give me some hints about it?

Comment: You can't use DI in Java SE, because DI is provided by a container. There may be frameworks around but I never used them, because if I wanted to use DI I simply used a container.

Comment: Also, in Java programming Language basics, when you call the main method, which is static, the class properties won't get initialized unless you call the class constructor.

Comment: I've updated my code but some errors are still present...

Comment: As long as your DAO relies on DI to get the entity manager you can't. You can of course get the entity manager somewhere else and then overwrite the DAO field with the "manual" entity manager instance after creating an object of that DAO in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use injection this way. I think that this is a short and nice article about how to use DI in Java: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DependencyInjection/article.html.

However, I would recommend you to use some framework, e.g. Spring (nice tutorial here: https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring).